# what's the use of ? operator before . operator in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in dart and currently I am learning, some where I show a method

```
Future<void> _showMessage(String message) =>
  _scaffoldKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(message),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      )
  )?.closed;
```

here I didn't get the use of ? operator before . operator is it same as Kotlin (mean checking nullability) or it's different.

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour

Answer (score 1):

It is Conditional member access.

Taken from Dart documentation

> Like ., but the leftmost operand can be null; example: `foo?.bar` selects property `bar` from expression `foo` unless `foo` is null (in which case the value of `foo?.bar` is null)

Source: [Dart Language Tour Documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)

Answer (score 0):

it's used for null check

**The operator roughly translates to "If the object is not null, access inner field, else return null."**

Example:-

To check object is null or not you have to write this much of code

```
Point point; 

if(point != null) {
    print(point.x) 
  } 
  else { 
    print("No value");
  }
```

But with "?" operator you can do it easily

```
Point point; 

int x = point?.x ?? 0;
```